# In scala, how can I use pattern match to match a list with specified length?

Tags: list, scala, functional-programming, pattern-matching

My codes looks like this:

```
1::2::Nil match {
  case 1::ts::Nil => "Starts with 1. More than one element"
  case 1::Nil => "Starts with 1. Only one element"
}
```

I tried to use `1::ts::Nil` to match the List who starts with `1` and whose length is greater than 1. It workes well for 2-element list, however, this pattern doesn't work for `3-element list`, for example:

```
1::2::3::Nil match {
  case 1::ts::Nil => "Starts with 1. More than one element"
  case 1::Nil => "Starts with 1. Only one element"
}
```

This won't work..Does anyone have ideas about this?

Comment: If you're interested in lists of specific length, you might be interested in Shapeless (https://github.com/milessabin/shapeless).  In particular, the HList stuff might be relevant for your problems.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You don't have to match on Nil. What you could do instead is match on the rest.

```
1::Nil match {
   case 1::ts::rest => "Starts with 1. More than one element"
   case 1::Nil => "Starts with 1. Only one element"
}
```

With this code rest is than either a List or Nil and you make sure that the element has more than 1 element with the match on ts and then rest

Comment: Improvement: `{ case 1 :: Nil => 1; case 1 :: rest => 2 }`.

Answer (score 4):

By rearranging the cases and adding a third case for completeness (exhaustive matching), this captures the intended semantics,

```
1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil match {
  case 1 :: Nil => "Just one"
  case 1 :: xs => "One and more"
  case _ => "Unknown"
}
```

Note the second case extracts the first element and the rest which cannot be an empty list (`Nil`) since this possibility did not match in the first case: here, `xs` includes at least one more non empty list; the last case covers empty lists.

Answer (score 4):

In addition to the other answers, you can also use the apply method of the companion List object like so:

```
1::2::3::Nil match {
  case List(1, _, _*) => "Starts with 1. More than one element"
  case List(1) => "Starts with 1. Only one element"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

To generalize this problem, you might write your own extractor.  To match on lists of an arbitrary length with a given first element, you could:

```
object HeadWithLength {
    def unapply[A](list: Seq[A]): Option[(Option[A], Int)] = 
        Some(list.headOption -> list.length)
}
```

And then you can match:

```
List(1, 3, 4) match {
    case HeadWithLength(Some(head), length) => println(s"Head is $head and length is $length") 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`ts` is matching one element of the list. In your first case, `ts` matches 2 i.e. `1` in the list matches with `1` in the pattern statement, `ts` matches with `2` in the list and `Nil` in the list matches with `Nil` in the pattern statement and you don't get any MatchError

```
1 :: 2 :: Nil match {
    case 1 :: ts :: Nil => println("ts is "+ts)
                         "Starts with 1. More than one element"
    case 1 :: Nil       => "Starts with 1. Only one element"
  } //> ts is 2
   //| res1: String = Starts with 1. More than one element
```

In your second case, you are trying to match ts with both 2 and 3 which is not possible and hence it throws a MatchError.

If you want to do a pattern match based on size, you can do

```
 
 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil match {
    case 1 :: tail if tail.size > 1 => "Starts with 1. More than one element"
    case 1 :: Nil                   => "Starts with 1. Only one element"
  }   //> res0: String = Starts with 1. More than one element
```

If case in the pattern match can be any condition for your real use case

Comment: `tail.size` is expensive and not needed here.