# scala : how to match a case by array length

Tags: scala

A newbie here.

We have some (possibly ugly) code that goes:

```
val rowSplit = line.split(",", -1)

rowSplit match {
  case array: Array[String] =>
  {
     if (array.length < 18) {
     //do sth

     }
     else if(array.length < 26){

     // smth else
     }
  }
```

I was wondering if we could match arrays with individual lengths directly in the case statement.

Is it possible?

*PS:  I donT know if this SO post answers my question. If so how?*

[In scala, how can I use pattern match to match a list with specified length?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28644861/in-scala-how-can-i-use-pattern-match-to-match-a-list-with-specified-length)

Comment: The type of `rowSplit` is already known to be `Array[String]`, so you don't need a pattern match to test that. I would get rid of the use of `match` entirely and just use an `if`/`else` chain.

Comment: then, what if the line is empty?

Comment: you'll get an empty array. an empty array is still an `Array[String]`.

Answer (score 8):

You can match the array and add a condition to the matching case like this :

```
rowSplit match {  
  case array:Array[String] if array.length < 18 => //do sth
  case array:Array[String] if array.length > 26 => ...
}
```

or simply:

```
rowSplit match {  
  case a if a.length < 18 => //do sth
  case a if a.length > 26 => ...
}
```

Note that here we can use [variable pattern](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#variable-patterns) `a` instead of [typed patterns](https://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.12/08-pattern-matching.html#typed-patterns) like `a:Array[String]` because we don't need further type matching of `rowSplit`, we knew `rowSplit` is of type `Array[String]`, and it has field `length`.